# Does vanilla JS project mean the project that was done without using any library or framework?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I used three.js, gsap, and mobx(a global state management library). Can't I just call this a vanilla JS project?

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com/

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS is a way of saying that the Javascript code is written without any libraries or dependencies.

Since you used three.js, gsap, and mobx, your project is not vanilla JS.

Answer (score -1):

If I was looking for a job and a potential employer claims I'd work on an vanilla js project, I would not feel deceived if:

- the overall structure of the project is not dictated by the library (which excludes angular, react, etc.).
- used libraries have a limited scope and therefore are more or less easily exchangeable (you can switch from chart.js to d3.js)
- I can understand, reason about and write code in an application logic module without looking up any documentation for the libraries used by the other modules (that's decoupling)
- the removal of a library does not force you to rewrite your whole codebase

There is an exception to the last rule: legacy codebases that depend on libraries like jQuery or underscore: I'd call a project "vanilla" if the team is committed to remove these dependencies and new modules are written without these dependencies.

In your case presentation (three.js) and animations (gasp) should be decoupled from logic. But MobX seems to be the deal breaker: it plugs deep into your classes and logic. This is not vanilla. In order to understand your code, a new developer not only has to look at your code, but also at the documentation for MobX.

Allthough MobX says "MobX is unopinionated and allows you to manage your application state outside of any UI framework." The first example they present is obviously react code, which repels me.